# Are AirPods damaging to your health?

Tags: airpods

I was looking online and found links to two articles about the potentially harmful effects of AirPods on the body.

[This is the first article.](https://besynchro.com/blogs/blog/why-i-stopped-using-apple-s-airpods-testing-emf-s-in-bluetooth-headphones). It links to a video where the EMF intensity of the AirPods was tested and compared to other bluetooth headsets. It was concluded that they emitted a relatively high average EMF intensity. It allegedly also has a "consistent field intensity... in the 7-10 milligauss (mG) range" as opposed to a varying amount, which is apparently has a greater magnitude of effect on "brain chemistry." Do note however that this site sells supplements, if that makes any difference in its validity.

[This is the second one.](http://macintoshhowto.com/hardware/extreme-emf-exposure-from-apple-airpods.html) It tests the AirPods (again, in a video) and sees that they emit EMF exposure which has a magnitude of 3500mV/m, which is ten times higher than an iPhone in a phone call (which is emits this exposure at a magnitude of 300mV/m). This also apparently continues to occur "even when you are not on the phone and not listening to any music." The author even tries to give an explanation for why this is occurring (such as because they need to transmit information to your iPhone continuously as they can't process "Hey Siri" on the devices themselves).

As the first article suggests, this might be a cause for concern, given that these AirPods literally sit inside your ears and many people don't even take them off for hours on end (even though they continue to emit this "EMF exposure"). I definitely would do that if I didn't know anything about this (which the average consumer most likely doesn't).

Additionally I've seen information about the AirPods being a Class 1 bluetooth device (power output 100mW, theoretical range 100m, [anecdotal range ~50m](http://www.idownloadblog.com/2017/01/09/w1-airpods-max-operating-range-vs-beats/)), which *does* seem strangely high for such small devices which stay so close to your body.

Apple's [RF Exposure legal site](https://www.apple.com/legal/rfexposure/) doesn't list AirPods for whatever reason – only Macs, iPhones, etc.

I'm not sure what to do here. I was on the fence about buying the AirPods but these concerns temporarily stopped me. If I should only wear them minimally to avoid potentially dangerous effects, it rather defeats the point of them in the first place, and it would put me off from spending $160 on them.

I haven't been able to find any actual studies of AirPods, only the aforementioned articles from these two sites (and one or two other random ones). As a side note, it's quite hard to find specific information about this online, as different sites come to wildly differing conclusions. It also doesn't help that on Internet forums there are many "armchair scientists" who claim something as being true based purely on personal belief or what they read somewhere instead of in fact. It doesn't help that there are sites like [this one](https://www.defendershield.com/are-wireless-bluetooth-headphones-safe) which criticize EMF-emitting wireless headsets (with what looks like a picture of a person wearing AirPods), which is likely to promote their own product.

I don't know how reliable the sources I linked in the beginning are, although I do know the latter was written by a "trained electrical engineer." The first one however is on a site which sells supplements, one of which enhances the "body's natural healing," which seems *kind of* fishy? I don't exactly know what to make of that one.

I must say that I do doubt that Apple would make such a rash decision as to put out a device on the market which could be detrimental to a person's physiological health. I'm not sure whether these articles are just spreading FUD or if they have a valid point (the articles do seem somewhat 'sincere,' although that admittedly doesn't say much).

What can I do? Should I avoid AirPods take these issues as valid concerns?

Comment: Those are genuine concerns that I think may have merit. Have you checked to see what AirPod competitors are rated at with EMF?

Comment: What a load of miserable dicks fsb, Allan, Scot and patrix are. Just because they can't answer the question, they want to stop other people from trying. Would asking if cigarettes are bad for you be primarily opinion based? It either is or isn't bad for you, that's a fact - not an opinion.

Comment: @Andre Thanks a lot for the support. I was wondering that it might be closed, since there perhaps *isn't* enough information to come to a definite conclusion. However, I think this is such an important issue that it would be nice if it got more attention and had some critical analysis performed on it by qualified people

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only question I could find in your entire statement is

> Should I avoid AirPods take these issues as valid concerns (sic)?

You posted info from sites that indicate it the levels of EMF emitted are both safe and not safe.

Apple has stated their products meet all applicable safety and health laws (although we all know these standards change over time).

For every site that I saw that stated it was safe, I found other sites (mostly natural-medicine sites) that said the opposite.

So to answer your question, it's completely up to you if you want to use them or not. I would say that based on the fact that you're concerned about this enough to do all this research (and still not come away with a definitive answer) that you should stay away from them and find another product that makes you more comfortable.